# What do we mean when we say a group has normal subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I said that a group $G$ has normal subgroups, does it necessarily mean that there is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $H \triangleleft G$, or could it also mean that there are subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ such that $H \triangleleft K$, but $H$ and $K$ are not necessarily normal in $G$?

In the latter situation, I could definitely see how one could say that $G$ has normal subgroups, even though they aren't normal in $G$.

Comment: It means the former, as the latter is always satisfied. For example, take $H = K$, or $\{1\} \triangleleft K$.

Comment: I would read it as saying that $G$ has at least two subgroups $G_1,G_2$ both of which are normal in $G$.  Of course, this is always true as we can take $G_1=\{e\}$ and $G_2=G$ so it's a bit of an odd thing to say.  I'd say it would be more meaningful to say that $G$ had non-trivial normal subgroups.

Comment: Where did you hear or read someone say this? It seems ambiguous to me; every group has at least one normal subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should mean $\exists N$ such that $N\triangleleft G$.  (If you say subgroups,  there must be more than one.)

In contrast,  simple groups don't have any nontrivial  normal subgroups (for instance,  $A_n,n\ge5$).

Also, whenever there's a normal subgroup,  it's the kernel of a homomorphism from $G$, and vice-versa.